# Use Omron libraries in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, libraries

I'm trying to use Omron libraries (i.e. Compolet) in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application. I added the assembly reference for those classes, but at run-time they try to locate the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly - obviously not available in ASP.NET Core.

The exact error is:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e096'. OMRON.Compolet.CIP.CIPPIcCompolet..ctor()

I guess "..ctor()" is "constructor". In fact this happens when I try to create a new object:

```
NJCompolet nj = new NJCompolet()
{
    LocalPort = 2,
    PeerAddress = "192.168.2.10",
};
```

I tried to add a reference to "System.Windows.Forms.dll" but it says:

> BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution. They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)

I also tried to use Reflection-only way but is again says that this mode is unsupported in this framework.

I'm aware I can create a separate Windows.Forms project just to instantiate the libraries but then I have to setup an IPC channel to exchange data with my main ASP project. I'm trying to avoid that - if possible.

Is there something other I should try?

Comment: As an aside, surely `NJCompolet nj = = new NJCompolet()` is a typo?

Comment: Yep, updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is you are trying to add a **.NET 2.0 Framework** DLL to a **.NET Core 2.0** project. These DLLs leverage two different run time environments which means they are not compatible with each other. You will need to switch your web application to a different run time that supports loading a 2.0 Framework DLL, like an ASP.NET 3.5 Framework project.

Comment: As far as I understand it's not only a mattet of runtime... The frameworks are quite different and I have to change a lot of code, haven't I?

Comment: Depending on the objects and style of code, yes you could end up changing a lot of code.